# Handling two objects does not exist errors

Tags: python, django

I have a `get_context_data` function for my `DetailView` Inside this function, I try to query two results. However, if the object does not exist then I get an error. If both objects don't exist, then I get two errors. I know I can do a try-except, but what if both conditions fail what is a more elegant way of catching both errors? I know I can do two try-except, but is there a better way specifically where I can make it so that the query does not return an object does not exist, instead it returns a default value?

Here's what I have:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

     context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

     try:
         vote = Voting.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user, 
         choice__question=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
         context['voted'] = vote[0].choice.id

         context['follower'] = 
         .object.user.followers.get(follower=self.request.user)

     except:
         context['voted'] = 0

     return context
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `queryset.exists()` could judge if a queryset is empty.Hope this could help.

```
if Voting.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user,choice__question=self.kwargs.get('pk')).exists():
     #do your stuffs
else:
     #give it a default value
```

If you only want to get the first object after filtering, you can also try

- `.get()`: [Django's .get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get)
- `.first()` :.  [Django's .first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Edit: Make sure that your program is ready to deal with anonymous users and unexpected inputs,so the filter can get it's value properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code, it will not output errors when either of `vote` ,  `context['voted']` or `context['follower']` is empty. Hope this could help.

```
try:
    #do your stuffs

except:
       vote = ""
       context['voted'] = ""
       context['follower'] = ""           

return context
```